# How can I add a link to the Wordpress Admin Bar that runs my function onclick?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, admin

I am wanting to add a link to the Wordpress admin bar that will eventually purge all cache. At the moment I am trying to add the link to the admin bar but seem to be having problems.

I have followed a few methods I had found on Google, but for some reason I couldn't get them to work. (I don't know if this is due to the examples being outdated with the version of Wordpress?)

Here is what I am using so far:

```
function time_to_purge($wp_admin_bar) {
$args = array(
'id' => 'DaylesPurge',
'title' => 'Purge Cache',
'href' => '#',
'meta' => array(
'class' => 'DaylesPurge'
)
);
$wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'time_to_purge', 50);

function PurgeConfirmation() {
document.getElementById("PurgeConfirmation").innerHTML = "Are you sure you 
wish to purge the cash?";
}
```

**[EDIT]**
Never-mind, this works perfectly. It was a matter of a simple spelling mistake in my code that was preventing it from displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function time_to_purge($wp_admin_bar) {
$args = array(
'id' => 'DaylesPurge',
'title' => 'Purge Cache',
'href' => '#',
'meta' => array(
'class' => 'DaylesPurge'
)
);
$wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'time_to_purge', 50);

function PurgeConfirmation() {
document.getElementById("PurgeConfirmation").innerHTML = "Are you sure you 
wish to purge the cash?";
}
```